# wpf textbox binding datetime

Tags: wpf, textbox

Im trying to set date time to a textbox but that gives an exception: System.Windows.Data.Binding.Path' threw an exception.

If I use TextBlock   everything is fine.

any help will be appreciated

thank you

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

 <TextBlock   Name="block" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},  StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss '}"/>

 <TextBox   Name="block1" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},  StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss '}"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This binding works using a TextBox and should be what you're looking for:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,260,0,0" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, Mode=OneWay,  StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss '}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

this works fine when you set the Binding Mode in the `TextBox` to `OneWay` :

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="1"   Name="block1" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},  StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ',Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

this is due to the fact that the default Binding mode in `TextBlock` is `OneWay` and in `TextBox` is `TwoWay`