# Can I store my DateTime in european notation?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, mvvm

I'm trying to find a way to **store** my `DateTime`-object in the European notation. Right now, when I bind a textbox to the `DateTime`-property of my object, it displays as the MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm AM(or PM). The reason I want to save it in this notation, is that I can't alter the notation via `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM")`, because the same property is also used to update other `DateTime`-properties. It would require a lot of rewriting (everytime I retrieve the string to set another object's DateTime, I'd have to `TryParse` it back to a `DateTime`-format), so I'm trying to find out if there's a way to save it in a desired notation.

An example that obviously doesn't work, but brings the thought across,

```
public DateTime<dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm> ModifiedAt { get; set; }
```

I tried to see if I could force it to keep track in a different format like this,

```
public DateTime ModifiedAt
    {
        get { return this.modifiedAt; }
        set
        {
            var s = value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
            DateTime.TryParse(s, out this.modifiedAt);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

but to no avail. As I'm starting to doubt this is possible, I'm curious if anyone has come across this problem before. Maybe there is a way to alter the displaystring in the declaration of the binding? As I'm using MVVM, I've set my viewmodel as datacontext and my binding looks like this,

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedObject.ModifiedAt, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `culture` for current thread ( or curent ui thread) ?

Comment: Don't store `DateTimes` in any format, store them as `DateTime`. Format them when you want to display them, f.e. with `DateTime.ToString`. A `DateTime` has never an implicit format, it just has a value, like a number.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad I looked into that, but (if I understood it correctly) it would act inconsistenly because I'm using a lot of `await Task.Run()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok, so I should look into how I can have my binding call a `ToString` while I can still have the `MyObject.ModifiedAt` return a `DateTime`-property?

Comment: OK, why don't you just set `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` it's globally for all threads and tasks. I wrote an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896455/why-does-parallel-foreach-change-the-culture-of-its-threads/40897055#40897055

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad that should do the trick, I'm going to see if I can make that work. But how does it tie in to what Tim said, about not storing DateTime in any format?

Comment: Let me write an example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

format your DateTime Property in xaml.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyDateTimeProperty, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}"/>
```

[As explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453733/wpf-textbox-binding-datetime)

Comment: As I was just writing my own answer because I found a similar solution I saw yours. I'm going to propose an edit with the article link I found

Answer (score 2):

For displaying `DateTime` in different cultures ( such as European ) you need to set culture for the threads and since you have to use `Threads` and `Tasks` in your application, you must use code below to set default culture for all threads and tasks which will get created in the future.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

And if you need only to change current thread culture:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture;
```

Just like you I have a TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox"/>
```

If I set current Date/Time to `Text` property:

```
textBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

The date will display as `01.12.2016 13:27:58`

My Windows culture have been set to `en-us` format, as you can see `textbox` value is in `de-De` format.

[image]

**Update 1:**

For setting default cultures I recommend create a new constructor in `App` class like below, I tried and it works.

```
public partial class App : Application
{       
    public App()
        :base()
    {
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    }

}
```

Comment: This may be a really stupid question, but where do I write those first two lines of code? (`CultureInfo.Default ..` etc.). Right now I have them in my Constructor, but it doesn't seem to change anything?

Comment: @Ciphra `CultureInfo.Default ..` will only work for future threads not the current one.

Comment: yes, and the second 2 lines (`System.Threading ..` etc.) set the current thread-culture, but when I set those 4 lines in my constructor and run my app, nothing changes. It still displays in "en-US"-format as described in my post. Does that have to do with binding the `DateTime` directly to the textbox, and not calling `ToString()`?

Comment: @Ciphra
I updated the answer, please take a look on Update1.

Comment: I'm building a module within an application to which I have no direct access-rights. Thanks for your help but I didn't seem to get it to work the way you described unti your update, and your update is simply not possible in my scenario. The answer provided by blindmeis solved my problem in a much easier and more straightforward manner. Again, Thanks for your help !